# Open a URL with default broswer?

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-browser, qpython, pyjnius

I'm new developer in QPython (experienced with python), I want to open an url with user's default browser.

I tried `AndroidBrowser().open("...")` but, to my surprise, I got Segmentation Fault!
So I said OK, let's try to open it manually as activity, then I tried to import `jnius` and got Segmentation Fault as well.

Any suggestion how to fix it or other ways to open the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this happens just in console mode, so in other QPython mods it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.view('……')
```